# How to calculate the absolute value between each element and end of with a matrix or data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data looks like below  Column A and B.

```
Column A     Column B
  A           0.098
  B           0.076
  C           0.871
  D           0.837
  E           1.981
  F           0.736
```

I want to calculate the absolute value between each and all column A elements based on B column.

So the output should look like this, So each time one element values will be used to calculate abs.

```
           A                  B                     C                D   E   F 
  A         0          abs(0.098-0.076)     abs(0.098-0.871)  ..... 
  B  abs(0.098-0.076)        0              abs(0.076-0.871)  ..... 
  C           0.871       ......
  D           0.837       ......
  E           1.981       ......
  F           0.736       ......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column vector is `x`, you can do:

```
dist(x, upper = TRUE, diag = TRUE)
```

Example:

```
x <- setNames(1:5, LETTERS[1:5])
dist(x, upper = TRUE, diag = TRUE)
#   A B C D E
# A 0 1 2 3 4
# B 1 0 1 2 3
# C 2 1 0 1 2
# D 3 2 1 0 1
# E 4 3 2 1 0
```

> I don't want to use `dist`, oops I forget to mention it.

You can try `outer`:

```
abs(outer(x, x, "-"))
#   A B C D E
# A 0 1 2 3 4
# B 1 0 1 2 3
# C 2 1 0 1 2
# D 3 2 1 0 1
# E 4 3 2 1 0
```

> For sure `dist` is efficient, but then if I want to change to another criterion I cannot.

I think you want to see some more complicated example. Now here it is. Define a bivariate function:

```
f <- function(a, b) exp(abs(sin(a) + cos(b)))
```

We can use `outer`:

```
outer(x, x, f)
#          A        B        C        D        E
# A 3.981957 1.530086 1.160118 1.206625 3.080627
# B 4.261408 1.637467 1.084040 1.291306 3.296824
# C 1.976687 1.316566 2.337010 1.669499 1.529257
# D 1.241723 3.231509 5.736189 4.097783 1.605027
# E 1.519866 3.955358 7.021078 5.015674 1.964548
```

Note that `f` is not symmetric, i.e., `f(a, b) != f(b, a)`, hence the matrix is not symmetric.

Essentially, `outer` evaluates the function `f` at the grid expanded by `x`, `x`. See `?outer` for more.